# Testing GFCI Outlet with a switch

Tags: electrical

How to test GFCI outlet with a Switch to determine if it is working?

Comment: Have you tried a three-light tester or a night-light plugged into the outlet? Or is your concern trying to figure out what the switch turns on/off?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what you're talking about; is this a GFCI outlet with a switch that you want to test, or do you want to use a switch to test a GFCI outlet? (And, why don't you just turn the switch on and then press the TEST button on the outlet?)

Answer (score 3):

There are some jury-rigged ways to test it - essentially building a small device that will route a limited amount of power to the ground wire. But if you aren't 100% sure of what you are doing, that is a bit risky. The simple solution is a 3-light GFCI tester which you can use for routine receptacle testing as well as GFCI.
[image]

Comment: Keep in mind the legends on those 3-light testers are pretty useless - we call them "magic 8-ball testers".  Actually they are optimized for guiding *people wiring new buildings which have new-building kinds of problems*.

Comment: @Harper But despite the limitations of the lights, they are probably the easiest & safest way for the average user to test GFCI circuits.

Comment: Oh, and the lights are useful too... just not the *legends*.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is a hammer...

### Simulate a neutral-ground fault

Take a common 50 cent receptacle.   Connect it all wrong, as follows:

- Brass screws to neutral.
- silver screws to safety ground.
- connect the hot wire to nothing but cap it off for safety.

Tape off all the receptacle screws because they might be hot.

Get a big dumb load like a heater that has a switch.  Plug it in to this test receptacle, turned off.

Somewhere else in the circuit, plug in another big load.  It does not need an on-off switch and it does not need to be dumb.  Make sure it,s switched on.

Now go turn on the AC power.   The GFCI should hold while the big dumb load is off.  Turn it on.  It should trip the GFCI.

What's happening is that neutral current from the *other* large load is seeking all possible paths back to the service panel.   We are adding a path that bypasses the GFCI in an improper way.  The other load needs to flow a lot of current, because only a small amount will want to go via this big dumb load, which needs to be big to divert enough to annoy the GFCI.

### Simulate a hot-ground fault

Same, but now we are connecting the brass screws to hot, capping off neutral (treat it as dangerous, always) and still ground to the silver screws.   Now we need a small load, only 12 watts will suffice.  This should definitely trip the GFCI.

Comment: I don't think either of these is a reasonable recommendation for the "average user". For an electrician - absolutely. For a handyman or computer geek (me) or someone else who has a moderate amount of experience wiring things up, sure (though personally I won't do this). But: Flash neutral to ground is a great test **if and only if there is no hot/neutral swap anywhere in the circuit** (or rather, an odd number - if hot/neutral were swapped twice, you'd be OK ). So option 1 is **not recommended**, unless you first verify the wiring. Option 2 is **much** safer but I still don't like it.

Comment: Better?  I thought the  preconditions are "without buying anything".

Comment: I didn't see those conditions in this question. I've seen it elsewhere but not this time.